# Docker stops immediately upon running - EOF error

Tags: linux, docker, centos6

When running the docker daemon it stops immediately. Below is a tail of the /var/log/docker file. What could be the issue. I upgraded the kernel but it doesn't reflect  unless rebooted. (FYI using vagrant on macosx(mavericks) The box is running centos-6.6

```
\nThu May 21 05:14:27 JST 2015\n
time="2015-05-21T05:14:27+09:00" level="info" msg="+job serveapi(tcp://0.0.0.0:2376, unix:///var/run/docker.sock)"
time="2015-05-21T05:14:27+09:00" level="info" msg="WARNING: You are running linux kernel version 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.8.0."
time="2015-05-21T05:14:27+09:00" level="fatal" msg="EOF"
```

The docker version is 1.5

If i run yum list installed | grep kernel-lt I get the following

```
kernel-lt.x86_64     3.10.74-1.el6.elrepo
kernel-lt.x86_64     3.10.75-1.el6.elrepo
kernel-lt.x86_64     3.10.79-1.el6.elrepo
```

What could be the issue

Comment: I had similar issue. As far as I remember I merely enabled IP forwarding on host machine to make it work(not sure about this, would check tomorrow). You may take a look at [this](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/IPForwarding) and [this](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers-and-the-wider-world)

Comment: Post the output of `uname -r` from the CentOS box. Do you have the `device-mapper-event-libs` installed? you can check it with `rpm -q device-mapper-event-libs`

Comment: Device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.90-2.el6_6.3.x86_64

Comment: I updated the default directive in /boot/grub/grub.conf and that removed the kernel message. Uname -r now emits. 3.10.74-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64

Comment: There might be an issue with /var/run/docker.sock. Make sure that `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock` print something like 'srw-rw----. 1 root docker'